# How to get all images from a file in VB?

Tags: vb.net, file, directory

For some reason, the following code does not work:

```
Dim images = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath, IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories, "*.jpg")
```

It's supposed to get all .jpg images from the `\bin\debug` folder, but it throws an error:

```
Conversion from string "*.jpg" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I retagged to VB.Net as that's what this is

Comment: The closest overload is `(path, pattern, option)` you have `(path, option, pattern)` - swap the last 2 args